# Is it Possible to Use Lambda Expressions in Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am a C# developer learning Java. In C#, I create all my queries using lambda expressions, and inject the expression into the nHibernate session.  My signature is `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`.  The expression is based upon a generic entity (T) and executes a `boolean` condition.

```
var results = repo.find(t => t.property1 == something && t.property2 == somethingElse);
```

I have been searching JPA until I am going crazy trying to figure out how to do this in JPA/Spring.

I am unable to recreate this in JPA.  Am I missing something?  Is this not a feature in `JPA`?

Also `JPA` seems to be set upon a DTO, and what I have found is very little support to work with business objects that are not syntactically equivalent to the data tables. (I have not written a DTO in years as a C# programmer.  `Fluent.nHibernate` extracts the DTO process by mapping business objects to the database format.)

Comment: Could you show the code you've already tried in Java?

Comment: "Also..." This sounds like a second question. Please post it separately.

Comment: AFAIK JPA does not support this type of query. What it does support is defining queries something like `findByProperty1AndProperty2(String prop1, String prop2)` (not 100% correct syntax). In JPA you only need to map the columns for a table that you actually need. If you don't need a column, don't map it. And if you need additional fields, that are not in the database, you annotate them with `@Transient`

Comment: While my code is work code and I cannot share on this forum, I will try to come up with an example..  It may be a few days.

Comment: "In JPA you only need to map the columns for a table that you actually need"  Here is again an issue with JPA.  If I am pulling different parts of a table, based upon different needs, I would be forced to create multiple maps of the same table.  In C#, I was able to map business objects to multiple tables, query the data I need w/o extra data via the Select() linq function.  JPA team.  you need to look at a few things to add to help us who write Java.

Comment: "findByProperty1AndProperty2(String prop1, String prop2)"  works unless you are querying data with many criteria.  Also that is literally a "magic string", meaning the compiler may not know the difference and leave it as is.  But the runtime parsing can possibly fail.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same as in C# with nHibernate or even LINQ.

But if you are using Spring Data JPA you could use Criteria API in Specifications.

Docs:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications

Comment: Criteria works to a degree, but it does not allow any business rule expression to be injected.  It is frustrating that Java does not seem to want to keep up with the real world.  It seems like the type of repository must be in the domain in order to build business rules around getting a result set.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses.  It appears I will be using a different pattern for developing code than what I was used to with C#.  If the JPA team sees this, and wants to discuss some additional features that would help with databases, I would be glad to help.

Comment: The point is: LINQ was a massive change in the C# language. this has nothing to do with JPA. And I don't think that Java will change to make something like LINQ possible

Comment: You are right Simon

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [library](https://github.com/janhalasa/jpa-repositories-with-lambda-expressions) that allows you to write JPA queries as lambda expressions - easy to read and write, type safe and much shorter than regular JPA Criteria API. It even supports pagination.

Example:

```
List<E> entities = findWhere(
(cb, root) -> cb.and(
    cb.equal(root.join(Car_.model).get(CarModel_.vendor), vendor),
    cb.equal(root.get(Car_.color), color))
```